# При повороте экрана Fragment меняется на предыдущий

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-viewpager

Есть одна активити, в ней в контейнере меняются фрагменты следующим образом:

```
public void switchFragment(Fragment fragment, String tag) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment, tag)
                .addToBackStack(tag)
                .commit();
    }
}
```

Все фрагменты при повороте девайса пересоздаются нормально, кроме одного, внутри которого `ViewPager` (хотя возможно проблема не в нем). Данный фрагмент при повороте просто закрывается и отображается предыдущий. Пойдя debug-ом проблему не выявил. Метод `OnCreateView()` данного фрагмента вызывается и полностью проходит. Далее его код:

```
public class WordTranslateFragment extends Fragment {

private WordTranslateController controller;

public WordTranslateFragment() {
    controller = WordTranslateController.getInstance();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_translate_training, container, false);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);

    final ViewPager mPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    controller.generateTest();
    final WordTranslateSlideAdapter mPagerAdapter = new WordTranslateSlideAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), controller.getSize() + 1);
    mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        int currentPage = 0;

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int i, float v, int i1) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int i) {
            if(i == controller.getSize())
                mPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if(currentPage <= i && controller.swapToPage(i)) {
                currentPage = i;
            } else {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int i) {
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}
```

Также вот код **PageAdapter**

```
    public class WordTranslateSlideAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private int count = 0;

    public WordTranslateSlideAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int size) {
        super(fm);
        count = size;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        return WordTranslateSlideFragment.getNewInstance(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

И фрагмента страниц:

```
public class WordTranslateSlideFragment extends Fragment {

private static final String EXTRA_ID = "id";
private WordTranslateController.BlockWords block;
ArrayList<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
private int idSlide;

public static WordTranslateSlideFragment getNewInstance(int id) {
    WordTranslateSlideFragment f = new WordTranslateSlideFragment();
    Bundle bdl = new Bundle(1);
    bdl.putInt(EXTRA_ID, id);
    f.setArguments(bdl);
    return f;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_translate_adapter, container, false);

    idSlide = getArguments().getInt(EXTRA_ID);
    block = WordTranslateController.getInstance().getBlock(idSlide);

    final TextView aTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.aTextView);
    TextView qTextView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.qTextView);

    qTextView.setText(block.rightWord.getName());
    aTextView.setText(block.rightWord.getTranslate());
    aTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    buttons.add((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button));
    buttons.add((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button2));
    buttons.add((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3));
    buttons.add((Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button4));
    View.OnClickListener buttonListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button click = (Button) v;
            aTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if(click.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase(block.rightWord.getTranslate())) {
                click.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                blockButtons();
                WordTranslateController.getInstance().setResult(idSlide, true);
            } else {
                click.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                blockButtons();
                WordTranslateController.getInstance().setResult(idSlide, false);
            }
        }
    };
    for (int i=0; i < buttons.size() && i < block.answers.size(); i++) {
        buttons.get(i).setText(block.answers.get(i).getTranslate());
        buttons.get(i).setOnClickListener(buttonListener);
    }
    Random random = new Random();
    int z = Math.abs(random.nextInt()) % 4;
    buttons.get(z).setText(block.rightWord.getTranslate());

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам поможет передача в конструктор адаптера `ViewPager` не `FragmentManager`-а активити, а `FragmentManager`-a фрагмента:

```
final WordTranslateSlideAdapter mPagerAdapter;
mPagerAdapter = new WordTranslateSlideAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), controller.getSize() + 1);
```

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: @СтепанЛяшенко, тогда, боюсь, вам придётся отказаться от фрагмента с `ViewPager` вообще. И переделать его в активити. За годы разработки я не раз видел подобные вопросы, но кроме предложенного мною решения вариантов других не встречал.